# Ko computed reference object as this

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, scope

I can't seem to reference current object inside `ko.computed`

Here is example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/KpJyb/)

Here is sample of code:

```
var fruits = ko.observableArray([{
    cart: ko.observable(1),
    fruit: 'Apple',
    carts: ko.computed(function () {
        var tempCartList = [];
        if ( !! this.cart) tempCartList.push(this.cart());
        else console.log("Couldnot reference");
        return tempCartList;
    },this)
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your code tries to do exactly, but you can use function to make an instance of fruit object.

```
var Fruit = function(opts){
    this.cart = ko.observable(opts.cart || 1);
    this.fruit = opts.fruit || '';
    this.carts = ko.computed(function(){
        // some logic here
    })
}
```

And then in your fruits observable array create a new instance of Fruit object:

```
var fruits = ko.observableArray([new Fruit({fruit: 'Apple'})]);
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some scoping issue. I moved the object in the observable array in a separate constructor function and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/saP6v/

```
var crt = function(){
        var self = this;
        self.cart = ko.observable(1),
        self.fruit = 'Apple',
        self.carts = ko.computed(function () {
            var tempCartList = [];
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.cart);
            if ( this.cart) tempCartList.push(this.cart());
            else console.log("Couldnot reference");
            return tempCartList;
        },self)
}

var fruits = ko.observableArray([new crt()]);
```